# Theoretical question regarding differential equations with various options

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am brand new to differential equations and was asked the following:

The functions $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are solutions of a second order linear differential equation in interval $I$. Let $α_1$ and $α_2$ be real numbers. Establish which of the following conditions are necessary and sufficient for the function $α_1y_1(x)+α_2y_2(x)$ to also be a solution to that equation.

1. The equation is homogenous
2. The functions $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linearly dependent.
3. The functions $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linearly independent.
4. $α_1 = α_2$
5. $α_1 + α_2 = 0$
6. $α_1 + α_2 = 1$
7. $α_1 + α_2 = 1$ or that the equation be homogenous
8. None of the above
9. More than one of conditions 1-7 is a necessary and sufficient condition.

According to my analysis, 1. is correct, while 2-6 are incorrect. What throws me off is the wording of number 7: strictly speaking this means it is also correct, but it is only restating a combination of 1. and 6. as an "or/or" statement, which seems rather superfluous. I am worried I might be missing out on something without realizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, statement $7$ is correct. If $A$ and $B$ are statements, the statement $A \vee B$ is true if and only if ($A$ is true or $B$ is true or $A$ and $B$ are true). Since $7$ can be restated as $1 \vee 6$ and $1$ is true, $7$ is also true.

Comment: Thank you, Jan! It just seemed so superfluous to add such an option. It belongs to "logic", not to "differential equations"...

Comment: But then the right answer is actually 9, which makes it even weirder (because 1 and 7 are essentially the same condition)...

Comment: @dalta I agree with you. In my opinion the whole exercise is not really useful.

Comment: sorry that I am going back to this, but I have changed my mind: the question says "necessary and sufficient condition": number 7 is a necessary condition, but it cannot possibly be a sufficient condition, because 7 is 1 ∨ 6, where 6 is not true. Could you just doublecheck my reasoning? Thanks so much!

Comment: I would say it otherwise: $7\ \textit{is}$ a sufficient condition since when $7$ holds, $\alpha_1 y_1(x) + \alpha_2 y_2(x)$ is a solution. What you can discuss is whether $7$ is a necessary condition, i. e., if $\alpha_1 y_1(x) + \alpha_2 y_2(x)$ is a solution, whether $7$ holds.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And strictly speaking I guess it does hold: the first part OR the second part does hold when we have that solution (and it will of course always be the second part). Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: @dalta Yes, I agree with you.